# fetching data from postgresql database using php and populating a drop down list with the data using angular in a html webpage

Tags: php, html, json, angular, postgresql

I want to fetch state_name from table mstate2 in my postgresql database and using php and using angular populate the dropdown list with that fetched statenames. My connection is properly establisehd and i am able to display the fetched data in VsCode terminal. But when populating the dropdown i get undefined I checked using inspect element the data retrieved is getstate_shikhartest2.php(the code itself) instead of the query result encoded in json.

shikhar.test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic Dropdown List</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">

    <h1>Dynamic Dropdown List</h1>
    <hr />

    <div>`your text`
        States:
        <select ng-model="selectedState" name="states"
        ng-options="state.state_name for state in states">
            <option value="">--Select State--</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
       var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('getstate_shikhartest2.php').then(function (response) {
        $scope.states = response.data;
        console.log('Retrieved data:', $scope.states);
    }, function (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    });
}]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

getstate_shikhartest2.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$host = "localhost";
$username = "postgres";
$password = "sanskriti";
$database = "sanskriti";

// Connect to the database
$conn = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$database user=$username password=$password");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . pg_last_error());
}

// Set the character set to UTF-8
pg_set_client_encoding($conn, "UTF8");

$output = [];

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT state_name FROM public.mstate2");

if (!$result) {
    $error = ['error' => 'Query execution failed'];
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($error, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}

// Close the connection
pg_close($conn);

// Set content type and echo JSON with UTF-8 encoding
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

[terminal output of getstate_shikhartest2.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGoOu.png)
[shikhar.test.html on google chrome I expect the state_name instead of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OreH.png)

Comment: _"the data retrieved is getstate_shikhartest2.php(the code itself)"_ - so apparently PHP is not getting _executed_ based on HTTP requests in your test environment to begin with.

Comment: ...which probably means you're not running the website on a webserver capable of serving PHP. Make sure you're using something like Apache or IIS. The built-in test webserver in VS Code can't run PHP, for example.